# Ubuntu Studio randomly Freezes [20.04 , 20.10]

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, freeze, ubuntu-studio

I'm having a recurrent problem with Ubuntu Studio since 20.04 (now 20.10).

The system randomly freezes (maybe after weeks, maybe a couple times per day). Sometimes it's due to overheat, that happened a couple times rendering video, but in that case it's easy to fix by limiting CPU frequency, but sometimes the system simply freezes, it doesn't matter how many apps I'm running, or the total system workload, of if it's in idle mode only showing the desktop, and I'm unable to do anything appart from moving the cursor. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't work neither for open the terminal.

1. With `htop` and `psensor` running I can see it's not due to RAM, or overtemperature, but after the freeze the fans will spin at max speed after a few seconds.
2. I think is a kernel problem: I've used kubuntu, ubuntu, xubuntu, and PopOs without a problem, but the moment I install the ubuntustudio LowLatency kernel (from ubuntustudio-installer package) the system begins to freeze ramdomly. I've tried to install xandmod kernel but there's a bug in ubuntu that won't let xanmod kernel showing in grub.
3. The freezes happen both on Kde and Xfce, but in kde it happens more often.
4. It happens both with Nvidia and Xorg graphic drivers.
5. It's not only a graphic problem because all process stops after a minute (like music).
6. Same problem in a Dell 5700 laptop running ubuntustudio20.04

I would love to have more info, but I don't know how to save a log of the process running in the very moment of freeze (that will be there after the forced shutdown).

---

> Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 20.10
> KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5
> KDE Frameworks Version: 5.74.0
> Qt Version: 5.14.2
> Kernel Version: 5.8.0-50-lowlatency
> OS Type: 64-bit
> Processors: 8 × AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
> Memory: 11.7 GiB of RAM
> Graphics Processor: GeForce GTX 770/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: If this happened after installing the lowlatency kernel, maybe try reinstalling the standard kernel

Comment: Yes, i think that woul'd fix the problem, but have random freezes is way better than get xrun while recording audio (that's why i need a lowlatency kernel).

Comment: sudo apt-get remove & sudo apt-get autoclean